# JavaScript apply CSS to image and save it

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass

I've been looking for a way to convert my CSS style into an actual image:

profile.scss:

```
  .profile-image {
  position: relative;
  .img1 {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-mask: url("../pages/JoinUs/images/mas.png");
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .img2 {
    position: absolute;
    //float: left;
    transform: rotate(-26.5deg);
    -webkit-mask: url("../pages/JoinUs/images/mas.png");
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(80%) hue-rotate(359deg)
      saturate(1200%) brightness(100%) contrast(1);
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

profile.tsx:

```
class ProfileImage extends Component {
    render() {
        const {image } = this.props
        return (
            <div className="profile-image ml-3 ml-md-1">
                    <img className='lazyload px-2  img2' src={image } alt='image8' />
                    <img className='lazyload px-2  img1' src={image } alt='image8' /> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I should look for exactly, but I want to programmatically mix those 2 image tags in one file to be served later without styling it.
Is there any way I could do that?

Thank you

Comment: You need to draw your image on a `<canvas>`, apply your filters and everything, then the canvas can be exported to Base64 image and saved to a file

Comment: You could investigate html2canvas (see github). You give it the HTML element you want to convert to a canvas, though in your simple case @JeremyThille suggestion would be fine..